# Exclude toString method generation that comes with Lombok @Data

Tags: java, tostring, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a class that is annotated with `@Data`. But I want to exclude the `toString()` method and provide a custom toString.

I just defined a custom `toString()` method as I usually do if I was not using lombok and it seemed to work. Following is my example.

```
@Data
class SomeDTO {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;

    private String someReallyHugeString;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "someReallyHugeString size is: " + someReallyHugeString.length() 
                  + "property1 = " + property1 
                  + "property2 = " + property2;
    }

}
```

But wanted to know if this is the right way to exclude `toString()` from `@Data` and if there are any side effects  I am missing.

Comment: Don't use `@Data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `@Data` (but provide all the other annotations) that is has:

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @EqualsAndHashCode
 SomeDTO { .... 
     public String toString(){....}
 }
```

This way if you remove `toString` by accident, it will not be generated.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.

It is right way. You can provide any method generated by `lombok`. It will check that method already exist and skip generation.

> The same rule applies to the constructor (any explicit constructor will prevent @Data from generating one), as well as toString, equals, and all getters and setters

[by Lombok Docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)